Linear congruental generator
I am trying to understand the influence of the multiplier on the period of the PRNG $x_{n+1}=(ax_{n}+1) \mod 16$. If $a=5$ the period is $16$. Everything fine with that. If $a=8$ the period is $2$. Calculating the moduli produces (with seed $x_{0}=0$): $\mod x_{0}=0, \mod x_{1}=1, \mod x_{2}=9, \mod x_{3}=9, \mod x_{4}=9$ etc. So the assumption is confirmed. Can somebody explain to me Fig. $3.3$ then? I have no idea how the author arrived at these shapes. Fig. $3.2$ is cool with me. Can calculate all the numbers there.
Screenshot of the mentioned figures:


What book is this from?

It's from "Monte Carlo Methods for Particle Transport" by Alireza Haghighat. So far I am not actually blown away from it. Looking for better books on this topic.
